# Bookdown error seq.default for epub but not for pdf

Tags: r, epub3, bookdown

I am using bookdown to produce epub with math. I usually export muy bookdown book to pdf (latex) and epub3. With one specific file, running with pdf_book() option goes well, but when using epub_book() option I have this error:

```
render_book("tema25.Rmd", epub_book())


processing file: _main.Rmd
  |.................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


output file: _main.knit.md

Error in seq.default(dots[[1L]][[11L]], dots[[2L]][[11L]]) : 
  'to' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite
```

my yaml options are

```
---
title: "Title"
author: Me
geometry:
 paperwidth=9.0cm,
 paperheight=12.1cm,
 margin=0pt
webtex: /home/javier/Dropbox/sec/texsvg.hs
lang: es-ES
documentclass: book
toc: yes
---
```

How can I solve this?

Thank you

Comment: Can you make your .Rmd file reproducible and post it here?

Comment: `devtools::session_info('bookdown')` please, or try the latest devel version on Github if you have not done so. I might have already fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it. It turns out that it had to do with having equations like "\[ \]" and then a blank line. Taking out those blank lines the problem was solved.

EDIT: I later found out that using `$$...$$` avoids any kind of trouble.